# All laravel routes not found except default route on Vagrant

Tags: laravel, vagrant

installed Laravel with Vagrant on Windows 10 and for some reason all laravel routes not founded on:
Vagrant (Ubuntu 16 + Apache2):

Uncommented these lines on Vagrant File:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
config.vm.synced_folder "www", "/var/www/"
```

Apache 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin info@somesite.devs
ServerName somesite.devs
ServerAlias www.somesite.devs
DocumentRoot /var/www/somesite/public
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/>
 Options FollowSymlinks
 DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
```

/etc/hosts :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu
192.168.33.10 somesite.devs
```

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts :

```
192.168.33.10 www.somesite.devs
```

C:\www\somesite\public.htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mod_rewrite isn't being allowed to do its job so you can't get to any urls that use pretty urls. You can only get to the index.

You are missing (or something like it):

```
AllowOverride All
```

in your host configuration for the directory in question.

Though it looks like you want a separate vhost for this site.

Comment: excuse me where to put this exactly? i've just add this on my Apache 000-default.conf like this : <Directory "/var/www/somesite/public">AllowOverride All</Directory> but still not working...

Comment: and you restarted the server?  you might have to read about apache configuration or do more digging

Comment: I just found the solution lagbox. It was a About Apache2.conf, i've edited this directory : <Directory /var/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>

to 

<Directory /var/www/somesite/public>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory>

thanks btw